# How to give auto numbering for HTML form field using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to give auto numbering in the form for different users. If one user logs in and inserts the data, I want to get the filed number as 1 and press next button and redirect to the form filling the another data number be 2, like that.

If a second user logs in and fills the form, they need to get the form number as 1 only as per the login id and date.

My HTML table:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .data{ 
        background : #e0e0a0;  
        padding:5px;
        align:center;
        height:200px;
        width:500px;
        float:left;
        margin-right:200px;
        margin-left:400px;
        border:1px  #000000;
        border-radius: 0px ;}

      </style>
 </head>
 <script>
   var i = 1;
   function buttonClick() {
       i++;
       document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
   }
 </script>
<body> 
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['useremail']))
{
    ?>
    <div class="data">
        <form name="f1" method="post" action="material_action.php">
            <table border="0" width="500" align="center" class="demo-table">
                <tr>
                    <th align=center colspan=2><h1>Materials</h1></th>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><b>Code    :</b></td><td><input type=number name="code"class="counter"id="inc" value="1" required autofocus placeholder="slno:" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td><b>Materials:</b></td><td><input type=text name="material"  required autofocus placeholder="16mmply"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>shade:</b.</td><td><input type=text name="shade" required autofocus placeholder="bsl/osl" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Grains:</b.</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="grains" value="grains"> grains<br></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <tr><td>
                  <td><td><input type=submit value="NEXT"class="increment-btn"onclick="buttonClick();" name='button'>
                  <input type=submit value="VIEW" name='button'>
                    <input type="submit" align=center name="submit" value="OK" class="btn register"><br/></td></tr>
                  </tr>
                  
                   </form>
          </table>
 </div>
<?php
}
else
{
    header("location:login1.php");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code

```php
<?php
    session_start();  
    $counter=1;    
         
     if(isset($_POST)& !empty($_POST))   
     {
         $counter++;
         $sql="select custcode from users where useremail= '". $_SESSION['useremail'] ."'";
                   require'connect.php';
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    $code=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                    $company=$code['custcode'];
                    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    if($count>0)
                   {
                     $cust=$company.date(" dmy");
                    $_SESSION['customercode']=$cust;
                   }
        $code=$_POST['code'];           
        $material=$_POST['material'];
        $shade=$_POST['shade'];
         $cust=$_SESSION['customercode'];
        $grains=$_POST['grains'];
        
        
        
           if($code=='')
            {
                header('location:./reg.php?error=Generate the code for materials!!!');
                exit();
            }
            if (isset($_POST['grains']) && ($_POST['grains'] == "grains")) {
     $grains .= "grains";
    } else {
     $grains .= "--";
    }
       
        
               $q="insert into material(code,material,shade,grains,customercode )values('$code','$material','$shade','$grains','$cust')";
              
             require'connect.php';
             $result=mysqli_query($con,$q);
        
         if($_REQUEST['button']=="NEXT")
           {
                $_SESSION['Quantity']=$qnt;
            
            header("location:material.php");
           }
         else
          {
           $errcode=mysqli_errno($con);
          }
        if($_REQUEST['submit']=="OK") 
         {
        header("location:data.php");
         }
       else
       {
        echo"try again";
       }    
                   
    }
       
     
    ?>
 <?php
       session_start();  
$counter=1;    
     
         if(isset($_POST)& !empty($_POST))   
 {
     $counter++;
     $sql="select custcode from users where useremail= '". $_SESSION['useremail'] ."'";
               require'connect.php';
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                $code=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $company=$code['custcode'];
                $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if($count>0)
               {
                 $cust=$company.date(" dmy");
                $_SESSION['customercode']=$cust;
               }
    $code=$_POST['code'];           
    $material=$_POST['material'];
    $shade=$_POST['shade'];
     $cust=$_SESSION['customercode'];
    $grains=$_POST['grains'];
    
    
    
       if($code=='')
        {
            header('location:./reg.php?error=Generate the code for materials!!!');
            exit();
        }
        if (isset($_POST['grains']) && ($_POST['grains'] == "grains")) {
 $grains .= "grains";
} else {
 $grains .= "--";
}
   
    
           $q="insert into material(code,material,shade,grains,customercode )values('$code','$material','$shade','$grains','$cust')";
          
         require'connect.php';
         $result=mysqli_query($con,$q);
    
     if($_REQUEST['button']=="NEXT")
       {
            $_SESSION['Quantity']=$qnt;
        
        header("location:material.php");
       }
     else
      {
       $errcode=mysqli_errno($con);
      }
    if($_REQUEST['submit']=="OK") 
     {
    header("location:data.php");
     }
   else
   {
    echo"try again";
   }    
               
}
   
 
?>
```

Comment: Is this a PHP question, an HTML question, or a MySQL question? Please be warned that your queries are highly vulnerable for SQL injection - have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand your question but if im right. What you need is setting a variable

```
$variable = 0;
```

And when something happens then just do:

```
$variable++;
```